# How is this program called?

Tags: software

[image]

I found this image somewhere on the internet and I am wondering what program is it.

Comment: You meant to ask which program was used to create it? Looks like eagle to me.

Comment: EasyEDA would be my guess.

Comment: It's not a program. It's a circuit, or a schematic. Do you want to know what it does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is probably [Eagle](https://www.autodesk.de/products/eagle/overview) (based on the default color scheme)